# Laravel | More than one CubePortfolio gallery in blade's view

Tags: laravel

how can I add more CubePortfolio gallery in my view. My code:

```
@foreach($page->subpages as $subpage)
    <div id="js-grid-lightbox-gallery" class="cbp ">
        @foreach($subpage->photos as $photo)
             <div class="cbp-item {{ $subpage->id }}">
                 <a href="/project/storage/app/{{ $photo->filename }}" class="cbp-caption cbp-lightbox" data-title="" rel="nofollow">
                     <div class="cbp-caption-defaultWrap">
                         <img src="/project/storage/app/{{ $photo->filename }}" alt="">
                     </div>
                 </a>
             </div>
        @endforeach
    </div>
@endforeach
```

currently only shows one gallery to me, and should display multiple galleries. One is ok, the other revolves around the loader.

I understand that there cannot be two galleries with the same ID? How can I solve this problem? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Append an identifier from the loop to the ID, the same way you do that with the class

```html
<div id="js-grid-lightbox-gallery-{{ $subpage->id }}" class="cbp">
```

Then initialize the element like so (example from jQuery)

```js
$('[id^=js-grid-lightbox-gallery]').cubeportfolio({
```

Hope this helps